# Ionic cordova network information plugin not working in ios

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I have installed the cordova-plugin-network-information typing:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

plus I added the ng-cordova.min.js in my index.html. The plugin works fine in android using:

```
if(navigator.connection.type == "none"){
        $ionicLoading.hide()
        $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: "Internet Disconnected",
            content: "There is no internet connection. Please check the connection and try again."
        })
        .then(function(result) {
            ionic.Platform.exitApp();
        });
    }
```

but in ios (through ionic emulate ios) the app does not even load. Any idea?

Comment: Try posting the error trace. Else try installing the app on ios device and inspect in safari for any console error trace

Answer (score 0):

You should Try these steps . maybe your plugin isn't get updated in the root of project

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-network-information
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
cordova build.
ionic run ios
```

maybe this will help you :)

Comment: Ok my bad that I wrote Android as platform .. did you try it ?